# "SourceIndex#each is deprecated". How to rectify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, deprecated

While running a Ruby on Rails program, I get a warning like this:

> NOTE:
> Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will
> be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
>
> Gem::SourceIndex#each called from
> C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:123.
>
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will
> be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
>
> Gem::SourceIndex#each called from
> C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:124.

How to set this right and what does it mean here?

I work on a Windows environment with the following configuration:

- Ruby 1.8.7 [i386-mingw32]
- Rails 2.3.11
- gem 1.8.8

Comment: Do you actually *use* SourceIndex#each? if not - do nothing. Otherwise, let us know how and where you use it...

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation warning is coming from Rails itself, as the backtrace notes. The intention of the warning is to warn you of imminent changes (2011-11-01) in Ruby's Gem class that may affect your Rails application.

As a solution for your Rails 2.3.x application, you could either:

1. [alter it to use Bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html); or
2. upgrade it to a more recent version of Rails (e.g. 3.0.x).